# Type constraint multiple possibility?

Tags: c#, types, constraints

Is there a way to put a type constraint where a type can be either of one type or another?

something like that:

```
    public void ParseXML<T>(T param) where T : XElement or T : string
```

**EDIT:**

According to your answers (thank for those), I guess I'll go this route:

```
public void ParseXML(XElement param)
{
    this.parseXML(param)
}

public void ParseXML(string param)
{
    this.parseXML(param)
}

public void parseXML(object param)
{
    var paramXElement = param as XElement;
    var paramString = param as paramString;
    ...
    <common proccess on param>
    ...
    <specific process on paramXElement> [if not null]
    <specific process on paramString> [if not null]
    ...

}
```

Comment: no you can't T must be a common super class of both types in the class hierarchy (hence useless "Object" for your example) or an interface shared by both of your types (for your example, you would have to encapsulate your types)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. How would you differentiate between one type or the other inside the function?
Even then, you'd probably have to do a type check and specialize, which defeats the purpose of *generic* method.

If you have two distinct possibilities, it would be the easiest to provide two specialized overloads:

```
public void ParseXml(string val)
public void ParseXml(XElement element)
```

And possibly the generic version for any other type, if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I would just create two overloads:

```
public void ParseXML(XElement param);
public void ParseXML(string param);
```

I don't see the point of the `T` here.

If the string method is supposed to take XML in a string, I would just make that method wrap it up in an `XElement` and call the other, so that you don't duplicate the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this really.

What I would suggest is constraining by `XElement` only, and then providing an `explicit` operator for that class taking a `string`, see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. You have two options:

1) Write two overloads of `ParseXML()`, one for each supported type. It would no longer be generic.

2) Do not have a constraint, but test the type at runtime. In this case, you use `object` instead of generics:

```
public void ParseXML(object param)
{
    var asString = param as string;

    if (asString != null)
    {
        // Do something with string.
        return;
    }

    var asXElement = param as XElement;

    if (asXElement != null)
    {
        // Do something with XElement.
        return;
    }

    // Error handling.
}
```

Clearly the first approach is better since it avoids the possibility of runtime error.

Comment: I'll use a mix of both approaches. 2 public overloads directly using another but private method where param is just an object.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant.

You should create an overload that accepts a string, wrap it in an `XElement` then delegate the call to the actual method